# Escape special characters in JSON encoded string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout with MVC and the standard method i've seen to get a view model for knockout is like this:

```
var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(model);
```

But if my model has string properties with special characters in them, e.g. '\r\n' I get a JSON parse error 'unexpected token'.

So I believe I need to escape these characters so they are like '\\r\\n'. How to do this?

I know I can just do this for this particular case:

```
var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model).Replace(@"\", @"\\"))';
```

but there may be others... tabs, single quotes.

Below is an example of the actual rendered model in the browser:

```
var model = '{"Id":4465,"TextContents":["EYE FILLET STEAK\r\nLINE 2 IS HERE"]}';
```

Comment: That looks like a valid JSON to me. Why is it enclosed in quotes though?

Comment: It has to be as far as I know due to way MVC wants to do things. Its a syntax error in the Razor view if I remove the quotes.

Comment: Paste the error. You shouldn't need the quotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `model` is a string, not a JSON. It evaluates escape characters before JSON parsed (if at all?)
Why do you need the quotes? Just remove them.

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

Comment: Hmm.. that works. Visual Studio is telling me its a syntax error but it compiles and works fine in the browser. Stupid VS2012 I guess. Thanks.

Comment: Try this `var model = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));`, see if it fixes the warning. Unfortunately I don't have VS on hand to try.